# Accepting user input during login

Tags: php, authentication, yii, roles

In my app the user may belong to multiple groups. But the requirement is such that I need to display records/options only for one group which the user will choose while logging in. Right now I am just getting the group id and setting it with setState in the authenticate() method of UserIdentity, which works fine if the user belongs to only a single group. However, if the user belongs to multiple groups I need to provide them with a choice to select which group he/she wants to be logged in to. How do I get that input from user right from UserIdentity/authenticate? Or if that is not possible what is the nearest solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You authinticate user;

   1.1. User has only one group:  `setState('GroupId', $GroupId)`

   1.2. User has many groups: you redirect him to `special page`, where he
           can choose his group.

   1.2.1. When user selected group, you setState('GroupId', $GroupId), and redirect back to site's page
2. If User not have GroupId, you redirect him to `special page`.